# what's the meaning of "it is not the case that"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of: "it is not the case that"

However, it is not the case that there has been 
substantial, or even adequate, theoretical conversation and debate 
about these terms and their usage

Comment: It is not the case... The fact is that there has not been substantial...

Comment: It is *not* the [situation]9http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/case), i.e. no conversation or debate has taken place.

Answer (score 11):

"It is not the case" is a more formal way of saying "it is not true".

Comment: I see that quite often people use "***this*** is not the case", "***this*** is not true". Not "***it***"...

Comment: Where do you live? It might just be a regionalism.